# Boeing 737-800 Source Off Light and Flight Director Bias Out Of View Function

Tags: boeing-737, flight-director

I have seen the following occur during simulator events. With a left Source Off light illuminated and the captain's autopilot and autothrottles engaged (or re-engaged):

- Captain's flight director lateral guidance cue will bias out of view when the autopilot is disengaged PRIOR TO glideslope capture.
- Captain's flight director vertical guidance cue will bias out of view when the autopilot is disengaged AT glideslope capture.
- Flight director will bias into view when either autopilot is then engaged.
- Flight director will bias into view when either pilot selects TOGA.

I do not know why the above occurs. If anyone can explain this, I would be grateful.

Comment: I do not have access to any 737-800 prints. Can you please explain the "Source Off" light. Are we talking the FCC itself or primary inputs like the IRS, ADC, ILS, or any other required valids.